# Which CPU usage reflects the true picture?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, cpu-usage

I am running a multi-thread Java application on Ubuntu. I want to watch the CPU usage.

The reading I saw from "System Monitor" is around 42% over time. Does this mean most of the CPUs is not fully utilized? I have 8 cores.

However, if I watch it in 'top' command, it shows that my Java application is using over %300 CPU (one PID).

Which reflects the true picture of my CPU utilization? I want to see whether and how my Java application benefits the threading.

Comment: It sounds like your program is using about 3 cores' worth of CPU (~300% of one core, or ~42% of the entire 8-core box). I'd say the two numbers are roughly in agreement.

Comment: Seems like "System monitor" is using 100% = 8 cores under full load, while top uses 100%= 1 core under full load. So you seem to have about 3 cores maxed out.

Comment: Probably the 42% figure relates to the processor while the 300% (8 x 42 = 336) to a single core.

Comment: "about 3 cores maxed out" does this mean other 5 cores are pretty idle, and I can increase the number of threads my application will use to speed up?

Comment: @NPE, you mean 300% is for one core? Are the other 7 cores idle?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/174660/why-is-the-cpu-usage-reported-by-top-in-linux-over-100

Comment: Beyond that: more threads only lead to better results when those threads are doing a lot of **waiting** (for example for IO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, top on Linux runs in so-called IRIX mode.

With IRIX mode on, 1 fully utilized core is 100% and 3 cores are 300%.
With IRIX mode off, 1/8 fully utilized core is 12.5%.
This means in top it shows over 300% and in "System Monitor" 40%.

You can toggle IRIX mode while top is running with **Shift+i**. This will make the numbers match up.

Comment: Terrific! does this mean I can still increase the number of threads to speed up even further my application?

Comment: Yes. From your example, it looks like you have roughly 5 cores underutilized.

Comment: I increased the count of threads from 10 to 20, the CPU usage only increased to 50% from 40%. I will try 50 threads. But I need to wait to see whether my application actually completes in shorter time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the time isn't shortened, even though CPU is better used with more threads.

Comment: Time to complete the task is definitely a better performance metric than CPU load. If you add more and more threads, you might either reach a point where this doesn't help (e.g. because IO becomes the bottleneck) or even where it decreases the performance (e.g. due to higher synchronization overhead, thread scheduling overhead etc.).

Comment: @user697911 With 8 cores I would recommend a maximum of 16 threads, since the CPU has 16 virtual cores. Anything more would force the JVM to switch a lot around, which does increase CPU usage, but not performance. somewhere between 12-14 cores should be optimal. Try changing you energy settings to increase the total performance if you really want to go to 100% usage

Comment: @user697911 On a more theorical point of view, you can have a look at Amdahl's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law. The gist of it is that increasing the use of resources does not translate as a linear speedup, and even worse, is definitely bound.